# non deductible IRA income limitation in 2020

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I heard there is a non-deductible IRA and it can be converted to Roth IRA. I am just wondering if there any income limits for contributing to a nondeductible IRA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is never an income limit on non-deductible Traditional IRA contributions. There is also no income limit on doing Roth conversions. The thing to watch out for with the "backdoor Roth" is that you have no pre-tax IRA money at the end of the year in which you do the Roth conversion; otherwise it will be partially taxable.